# I need to change the css style of multiple <td> with the same id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have a table that's created with asp net using a foreach to iterate through the instances of the viewModel.
I need to change the bakcground color of those  but they all have the same id

**HTML**

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr id="test">
        <td>    
            <p class="small">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DT_CADASTRO_FORMATADO)</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DSC_NATUREZA_INICIAL)
        </td> 
    </tr>
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("document")
     .ready(function ToPink() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
                let tab = document.getElementById("test");
                if (tab.cells[1].innerText == 'foo') {

                    alert(tab.cells[1].innerText);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: For reason that only 1 id is allowed on an html page, you can't use `getElementById()` to target multiple elements. Use `getElementsByClassName()` or `getElementsByTagName()` to target multiple elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the IDs *should* be unique, but what you are looking for is a CSS class. Add a class to the `td`s and then use `document.getElementsByClassName` to pull all the elements with that class name.

Comment: or put ```id``` in table tag ```<table id="test">``` then use ```#test tr td { /** table css **/ }```

Comment: @nosousa if you can go ahead and mark this as the answer then so it resolves the question. Glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 0):

ID should be unique because getElementById function searches for only one element that is first present with given ID:

```js
alert(document.getElementById("nounique").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="nounique">1</div>
<div id="nounique">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give each table a class and in the javascript you query all TD elements

```
<table class="test">
  ....
</table>

<script>
var TDs = document.querySelectorAll(".test td");
for (var i=0; i < TDs.length; i++) {
  // use TDs[i] here to style your html
}
</script>
```

Ofcourse you may use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".test td").each(function(index) {
    // use $(this) here to style your html
  });
});
```

Comment: I found out that I needed to style just some td's, but thank you very much

Comment: If possible, give the td's you want to style a `<td class="test">` and then use `querySelectorAll("td.test")` or in jquery `$("td.test")`. But using css is also possible with `tbody > tr:nth-child(..) > td:nth-child(..)`